# Adding a column in python based on multiple iterating conditions or looping

Tags: pandas, iteration, multiple-columns, numpy-ndarray, calculated-columns

I'd like to create an extra column in python either using Pandas or Numpy based on iterating conditions ( I think that's the way to do it). ** If any value is "False" and with the same IDxx, then the extra column is IN otherwise is OUT**

```
| IDxx   | Tru/Fal  |
| ------ | -------- |
| 164    | True     |
| 164    | False    |
| 164    | False    |
| 165    | True     |
| 165    | True     |
| 165    | True     |
| 166    | False    |
| 166    | True     |
| 166    | True     |
| 167    | True     |
| 167    | True     |
| 167    | False    |
```

I tried a few options but I'm running out of ideas. As all IDxx's are different I can't get the loop working. There are only 4 IDxx's in this example, but in my real case, there are hundreds. I'd like the output to return the following

| IDxx | Tru/Fal | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 164 | True | IN |
| 164 | False | IN |
| 164 | False | IN |
| 165 | True | OUT |
| 165 | True | OUT |
| 165 | True | OUT |
| 166 | False | IN |
| 166 | True | IN |
| 166 | True | IN |
| 167 | True | IN |
| 167 | True | IN |
| 167 | False | IN |

Comment: Please provide reproducible example (i.e., dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `replace` as follows.

```
idx_gb = (df.groupby('IDxx')['Tru/Fal'].min() == False).to_dict() # key: IDxx, value: IDxx includes False or not
df['Answer'] = df['IDxx'].replace(idx_gb)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The df['answer'] only throws False values even if some of the df['Try/Fal'] values are True. Could you please double check it.

Comment: In my example code, it works. 
df = pd.DataFrame({"IDxx":[164,164,164,165,165,165,166,166],
                   "Tru/Fal":[True,True,False,True,True,True,False,False]})

idx_gb = (df.groupby('IDxx')['Tru/Fal'].min() == False).to_dict() # key: IDxx, value: IDxx includes False or not
df['Answer'] = df['IDxx'].replace(idx_gb).replace({True:"IN", False:"OUT"})

Comment: Thanks .. for some reason it wouldnt work with .min(). Once I used .max() instead it started working.. You are a genius.. thank you so much